# Why is my OpenMP program slow when running it with CLion and WSL, but fast when I compile it manually?

Tags: c++, openmp, clion

I have a very simple matrix multiplication program to try out OpenMP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
  const int N = 1000;

  double matrix[N][N];
  double vector[N];
  double outvector[N];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = rand() % 50;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    vector[i] = rand() % 50;
  }

  
  double t=omp_get_wtime();
  omp_set_num_threads(12);
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      outvector[i] += matrix[i][j] * vector[j];
    }
  }
  
  t = omp_get_wtime() - t;
  printf("%g\n", t);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it two ways:

1. Using my Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL), using `g++ main.cpp -o main -fopenmp`. This way, it runs significantly faster than if I comment out `#pragma omp parallel for` (as one would expect).
2. Using my CLion toolchain:

[It's a default WSL toolchain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfCtN.png)

And the following CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Fernuni)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# There was no difference between using this or find_package
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")

find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()
add_executable(Fernuni main.cpp)
```

This way, it runs about ten times *slower* if `#pragma omp parallel for` is there.

Why?

edit:

Here are my specific timings with various combinations of optimization settings and enabled/disabled pragma directive:

```
         OMP,O0       OMP,O3       O0           O3         OMP only     nothing
CLion    0.0332578    0.0234029    0.0023873    6.4e-06    0.0058386    0.0094753
WSL/g++  0.007106     0.0012252    0.0038349    5.1e-06    0.0008419    0.0021912
```

Comment: have you tried enabling optimisations?

Comment: It should not change anything if you use Cmake in WSL. Try it out to check that the command didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you give your times mine are: OMP and O0 0.003s, OMP and O3 0.0003s, just O0 0.01 and just O3 0.000003.

Comment: I edited the question to include timings

Comment: It seems I'm getting a speedup now (I don't understand why! Maybe because I restarted my PC?), but the speedup with CLion is still a lot smaller than I would expect. I also only ran each of these once

Answer (score 1):

You are mainly measuring the **overheads** of the operating system, the ones of the hardware, the ones of the  runtime and the effect of **compiler optimizations**.

Indeed, the computation time should be less than 1 ms, while the time to create the OS threads, to schedule them and to initialize OpenMP can actually be close the same time regarding the OS and the runtime (it takes between 0.3 and 0.8 ms on my machine to do only that). Not to mention that caches are cold (many cache misses occurs), the processor frequency may not be high (because of *frequency scaling*).

Moreover, the compiler can optimize the loop to nothing as it does not have any side effect and the result is not read. Actually, GCC do that with `-O3` without OpenMP but not with (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/44hqYoqEr)). This is likely because the GCC optimizer do not see that the output is not read (due to internal escape references). This explains why you get better timings without OpenMP. You should read the result, at least to check they are correct! Put it shortly **the benchmark is flawed**.

Note that using `-march=native` or `-mavx`+`-mfma` can help a lot to speed up the loop this case since these instruction sets can theoretically divide by 4 the number of instructions executed in that case. In practice, the program will likely be memory-bound (due to the size of the matrix).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and explains some things. I still don't understand why it is so much slower when run from CLion, though. I wouldn't expect there to be much overhead once the program is actually running

Comment: It seems related to system calls regarding the timings. At this granularity small difference in the configuration can have a strong impact. It is hard to tell without more information about what exact command CLion use internally. Check if `/usr/bin/c++` is exactly the same as you g++ executed manually. You should also check the environment variables are the same. The remote connection might also play a role. It would be interesting if the same problem could be reproduced with bigger data or with the OMP threads created before the benchmarked section.

Comment: Thanks. The executable is the same, I verified that earely on. I think I'm just going to stick to manually running this stuff for now